# I am not getting expected result.why?

Tags: sql, timestamp

My table structure

```
Name          Null Type         
------------- ---- ------------ 
T_NO               NUMBER       
T_NAME             VARCHAR2(10) 
ENTERING_TIME      TIMESTAMP(6) 
LEAVING_TIME       TIMESTAMP(6) 
TO_DATE            DATE
```

Insert statement:

```
insert INTO t3 VALUES
  (
    1,
    'ram',
    TO_date('01:36:51','HH:MI:SSAM'),
    TO_date('11:59:51','HH:MI:SSPM'),
    to_date('23-09-13','dd-mm-yy')
  )
```

My problem is: I specially mentioned  `LEAVING_TIME` in `PM` but it showing `AM`. I don't know why it showing like.

Is there any problem with this select:

```
select t_no,t_name, TO_CHAR(ENTERING_TIME,'HH12:MI:SSPM'),
TO_CHAR(LEAVING_TIME,'HH12:MI:SSPM'),TO_DATE from t3
```

Result is:

```
T_NO|T_NAME|TO_CHAR(ENTERING_TIME,'HH12:MI:SSPM')|TO_CHAR(LEAVING_TIME,'HH12:MI:SSPM')|TO_DATE 
1 ram        09:45:51AM                            04:45:51AM       23-SEP-13
1 ram        10:05:51AM                            11:00:51AM       23-SEP-13
1 ram        01:36:51AM                            11:59:51AM        23-SEP-13
```

Comment: i used that is also but am not getting@ a_horse_with_no_name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your queries are working as intended.

In your query,

```
TO_date('11:59:51','HH:MI:SSPM')
```

You have mentioned the Meridian indicator (PM) in the format, but you haven't given the value for it in the date string.
So, it is defaulted as AM.

What you need to do is write it this way.

```
TO_date('11:59:51PM','HH:MI:SSPM').
```

Note that 'HH:MI:SSPM' is simply a format specifier. It does not indicate whether the time is AM or PM. You can replace PM with AM and still get the same result.

Comment: ya i got it.is there any option for directly got time from dual into my table  ' insert INTO t3 VALUES
  (
    1,
    'ram',
    ((SELECT TO_CHAR(SYSDATE , 'HH12:MI:SSpm') as Time FROM DUAL);),
    ((SELECT TO_CHAR(SYSDATE , 'HH12:MI:SSpm') as Time FROM DUAL);),
   ((SELECT TO_CHAR(SYSDATE , 'DD:MM:YY') as Time FROM DUAL);)
  );' but it showing error

Comment: SYSDATE is of DATE type. Since your columns are of timestamp/date type, you can directly insert it. 
`insert into t3 values(1, 'ram', sysdate, sysdate, sysdate);` Also, you cannot store only time in DATE/TIMESTAMP columns. It will store both time and date.

Comment: y we can't store time.why?is there any alternate option